# R-How to retrieve previous one day data from present day data

Tags: r, mongolite

I'm using mongolite package to connect and retrieve data from MongoDB, please help me retrieve last one day data from present-day date and time.

```
##connecting mongodb

library(mongolite)

mongo<-mongolite::mongo(collection = "Sample", db = "Test", url = 
                          "mongodb://User:123@Wyyuyu:13333/ty2_U",verbose = TRUE)

## getting  data from collection

values <- mongo$find()
```

The above code steps are working fine for getting all the data from sample collection. But my need is to get only previous day data from present day data and time.

Example dataframe.

```
Get <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 firstName=c("kannan","anderson","jimmy","aray","stepen","james"),
                 dates =as.POSIXct(c("2017-10-25 15:10:59","2017-10-25 11:30:59 ","2017-10-24 15:30:59 ","2017-10-23 15:32:33","2017-10-24 11:22:34","2017-10-23 14:25:17")))
```

output dataframe

```
id   name      dte 
3   jimmy     2017-10-24 15:30:59

5   stepen     2017-10-24 11:22:34
```

Comment: @Hardikgupta,Thanks for u'r response .I have tried below post but i'm getting below result.                                                                                  [1] id        firstName dates    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.frame`(Get, Get$dates > (as.Date(Sys.time()) - 1) & Get$dates <  :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for ">"
2: In `[.data.frame`(Get, Get$dates > (as.Date(Sys.time()) - 1) & Get$dates <  :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for "<"

Comment: simply returning empty dataframe .   [1] id        firstName dates    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) . is I need to convert any time zone.

Comment: can you check your str(Get) and post the result, because when I checked the result was proper

Comment: 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id       : num  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ firstName: Factor w/ 6 levels "anderson","aray",..: 5 1 4 2 6 3
 $ dates    : POSIXct, format: "2017-10-25 15:10:59" "2017-10-25 11:30:59" "2017-10-24 15:30:59" "2017-10-23 15:32:33" ...

Comment: if I print the result like-  print(Get$dates),i'm getting     [1] "2017-10-25 15:10:59 IST" "2017-10-25 11:30:59 IST" "2017-10-24 15:30:59 IST" "2017-10-23 15:32:33 IST" "2017-10-24 11:22:34 IST"
[6] "2017-10-23 14:25:17 IST"

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your data like this

```
Get <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                  firstName=c("kannan","anderson","jimmy","aray","stepen","james"),
                  dates =as.POSIXct(c("2017-10-25 15:10:59","2017-10-25 11:30:59 ","2017-10-24 15:30:59 ","2017-10-23 15:32:33","2017-10-24 11:22:34","2017-10-23 14:25:17")))


Get[Get$dates > (as.Date(Sys.time()) - 1) & Get$dates < as.Date(Sys.time()),]

  id firstName               dates
3  3     jimmy 2017-10-24 15:30:59
5  5    stepen 2017-10-24 11:22:34
```

Comment: is this still giving you issue? Working fine with your example here